# Front panel audio sound not working

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

i use all of the this like alsamixer or the pulse audio volumn also not fixing the problem i am using asus taf gaming motherboard, is that why this all is not working, the rear audio is working fine but not the front audio panel of the motherboard but using the realtek solve this problem in windows but in ubuntu the problem is not solvable.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) And provide us more details. Also, when you read the [Tour page](https://askubuntu.com/tour) You will earn a badge when you read that entire page!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo alsamixer
```

You should be able to find your speakers somewhere in the alsamixer.